# Uninitialized constant Teaspoon::Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, jasmine, jasmine-jquery, teaspoon

Upgraded teaspoon 0.9.1 to teaspoon-jasmine 2.3.4. After running rails generate teaspoon:install getting 
    "Error: uninitialized constant Teaspoon::Framework."  error

```
[WARNING] Could not load generator "generators/teaspoon/install/install_generator". Error: uninitialized constant Teaspoon::Framework.
```

I am using jasmine framework.
Any idea why is it throwing Framework error?

Comment: any help on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this happened when my `Gemfile` only loaded `teaspoon` for the `:test` environment, but I ran `rails generate` implicitly in the `:development` environment.

You can either make sure the `gem 'teaspoon'` (or `gem 'teaspoon-jasmine'`) line is part of the Rails `:development` environment, or you can try running:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails generate teaspoon:install
```